# How do i make a new table out of two existing tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

Create a new table (order_id, customer_name and order_date) by joining two tables(order_id,
customer_id and order_date) and (customer_id, customer_name, contact_name, country)

I have to do this for a class and have been trying to do it for a while but cant find a solution. How do i do this?
Thanks

Comment: Read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html and  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html and if you still have problems post the code you tried and we'll try to sort it out.

Comment: Create SELECT which rpoduces needed data representation. Then add CREATE TABLE clause at the beginning.